# Firebase stripping the "+" sign from my phonenumber id

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase collection where I use phonenumber starting with "+" sign as ids.

So when I create a Firebase reference to update a counter, the Firebase reference is being created without the "+" sign, which results in a new row being created without the + sign. Why is Firebase stripping off the + sign?

The firebase ref I create like this:

```
String id = "+919920801121";
Firebase callCounterRef = new Firebase(FbDbHelper.FB_PROJECTS + projectId + "/leads/" + id + "/callCounter");
```

This prints the ref as following:

```
https://myapp.firebaseio.com/projects/-K0QiZGSCTobFLE8TItb/leads/%20919920801121/callCounter
```

this results in a new lead being created with phone number 919920801121, where as the earlier lead exists with number +919920801121

How can I get pas this problem?

Comment: The URL passed into Firebase() is going to be passed into an HTTPS request and a wss:// request. Thus, it must be a valid URL. You must urlencode any parameters you pass into there. Try `new Firebase(base_url).child(projectId+'/leads/'+...)` to avoid this.

Comment: `+` is a special character is urls. often it means space, which is here encoded as `%20`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution.

Instead of creating a unified path, I use .child() method, which preserves the + sign, like below:

```
Firebase callCounterRef = new Firebase(FbDbHelper.FB_PROJECTS + projectId + "/leads/").child(id+ "/callCounter");
```

This respects the child key and does not encode the result, which the above was doing.